# Regex to match digits, commas, and specific words

Tags: c#, regex

**I'm trying to set up regex that would match the following:**

```
hot 8,6,4,2,1,7
```

**This is the code that I have worked on so far, neither of which are specific enough:**

```
^(hot)|(cold)|( )([8])
^(hot)|(cold)|([1-8])|(,\d{1})
```

**Here's the requirements that I need to force a check on format:**

1. The regex should match lower case words, either "hot" or "cold"
2. Numbers cannot be outside of range `[1-8]`
3. If string has either words `hot` or `cold`, there has to be a space and an 8 following the space; for example, `hot 8` or `cold 8`
4. last character in string should end with a number (no space or character)

Some help with this would be immensely appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: The requirements are not quite clear. Try `Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(?:hot|cold) 8(?:,[1-8])*$")`

Comment: Use @Wiktor Stribiżew regex and change `8` to `[1-8]` and you are good to go. https://regex101.com/r/61LLxd/1

Answer (score 0):

((hot 8,)|(cold 8,))?(/d,)+/d

So I may have miss typed the regex symbols correctly but I’m on a phone and have no quick reference, but I know the rules Exist if that helps. but the explanation is basically..

“hot space number” or “cold space number” (zero or 1 time) then and amount of numbers followed by a comma (1 or more times) then a final number with no finishing comma.

Sorry about my answer formatting... mobile device.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The problem that I'm having is that the example string I posted could change based on user input. So it could be cold 1,2,3,4 and then hot 3,2,4,2,2,6. How can I check to ensure that a comma follows each number except for the last number?

Comment: @shoppers1d3e *If string has either words "hot" or "cold", there has to be a space and an 8 following the space* - how come you now say there can be `cold 1,2,3,4` or `hot 3,2,4,2,2,6`?

Comment: My regex does this, you stated a rule where the number 8 must come after the word hot or cold which is handled first and then we handle the second chunk. To go to your example of hot 3,2,4,2,2,6 (I will change the 3 to an 8 as your instruction). We first deal with “hot 8,” or “cold 8,” first comma being included. Then account for any amount of number comma pairs like this (/d,)+ this says any number and a comma 1 or more times (I’m guessing + means 1 or more you may need to check for me sorry). Then we need to finish with a number so we add another “/d” on the end

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(?:hot|cold) 8(?:,[1-8])*$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUBMcn/1).

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:hot|cold)` - `hot` or `cold` substrings

  - `8` - space and `8`
- `(?:,[1-8])*` - zero or more (`*`) occurrences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[1-8]` - a digit from `1` to `8` (tune as you see fit here)
- `$` - end of string.